# Removing the quotations marks from the bibliography using harvard style (agsm)

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation, harvard-style

I'm pretty new to using LaTeX but have so far found it fairly intuitive and am currently using it to write my dissertation. I am using the `harvard` and `natbib` packages to cite and create my bibliography.

I am using the `agsm` style to create the bibliography and end up with this:

> Leopold, L. & Maddock, T. (1953), ‘The hydraulic geometry of stream channels and some physiographic implications’, U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper 252, 1– 56.

As opposed to what I need being this:

> Leopold, L. & Maddock, T. (1953), The hydraulic geometry of stream channels and some physiographic implications, U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper 252, 1– 56.

I need to remove the quotation marks at the start and end of the contents of the `title` field, but I'm not sure how.

The BibTeX code for the reference is

```
@article{leopold1953,
 Author = {Leopold, L.B. and Maddock, T.},
 Date-Added = {2012-03-10 11:33:51 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2012-03-10 12:14:58 +0000},
 Journal = {U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper},
 Lccn = {gs53000079},
 Pages = {1-56},
 Series = {Professional paper},
 Title = {The hydraulic geometry of stream channels and some physiographic implications},
 Volume = {252},
 Year = {1953},
 Bdsk-Url-1 = {books.google.co.uk/books?id=cA%5C_WYgEACAAJ}
}
```

Comment: could you post the bibtex source for that line, it would help see what is going on.

Comment: @article{leopold1953,
 Author = {Leopold, L.B. and Maddock, T.},
 Date-Added = {2012-03-10 11:33:51 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2012-03-10 12:14:58 +0000},
 Journal = {U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper},
 Lccn = {gs53000079},
 Pages = {1-56},
 Series = {Professional paper},
 Title = {The hydraulic geometry of stream channels and some physiographic implications},
 Volume = {252},
 Year = {1953},
 Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cA%5C_WYgEACAAJ}}

Comment: Off-topic: One shouldn't load both the `harvard` citation management package *and* the `natbib` citation management package. Choose one or the other, *but not both*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make yourself a copy of agsm.bst, and call it agsm-nq.bst (in the same
directory as your document).

edit agsm-nq.bst, and search for the line with "FUNCTION {article}"

the start of the function is:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
  author "author" item.check
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title quote "title" output.check }
...
```

in the last line, there, there's the function that puts the quote in.
change the line to read:

```
    { format.title "title" output.check }
```

now change

```
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{agsm-nq}
```

in your document, and the quotes won't be created.

you can do similar things to other reference types, if they too have that `quote` function in them

Comment: @wasteofspace I tried recently your answer but with no success, I use TexStudio and MikTek in windows, any idea?

Comment: sorry for the noise, I had to run first F11 (bibliography), then F1, thanks for the nice trick.