# An issue about the single quote mark appeared in bibliography using `natbib` with `agsm` style

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I have settled on `natbib` with `agsm` style. And have a problem similar to the ones in the postings [Removing the quotations marks from the bibliography using harvard style (agsm)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47520/removing-the-quotations-marks-from-the-bibliography-using-harvard-style-agsm) and [Fine tuning natbib for agsm bibliography style, and adding links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65942/fine-tuning-natbib-for-agsm-bibliography-style-and-adding-links). You can have a look at the answers given for these posts. That is, changing the `agsm.bst` file does work for the `article` form. After changing the `agsm.bst` file according to the answers, I do not have any single quote mark anymore on my bibliography for articles. But for the **@inproceedings**, I still have the single quote mark around the `booktitle` field. It looks like, for example:

> Herman, G. (1974), Reconstruction of binary patterns from a few
>   projections, in ‘International Computing Symposium 1973’,
>   North-Holland Publ. Co., Amsterdam, pp. 371–378.

You can see the single quote marks.

I looked at the `agsm.bst` file of the proceedings part but I don't know which part to change. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

You can try this as sss.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

\citep{sss}
\bibliography{sss}
\end{document}
```

and this is my sss.bib:

```
@inproceedings{sss,
author = "G. Herman",
title = "Reconstruction of binary patterns from a few projections",
booktitle = "International Computing Symposium 1973",
publisher = "North-Holland Publ. Co.", 
address = "Amsterdam",
pages = "371-378",
year = "1973"
}
```

How can I get rid of the single quote mark around 'International Computing Symposium 1973' in the References section?

Comment: Welcome! Please give us a complete, small example we can copy-paste-compile to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the case at hand, you'll need to edit the function `format.in.ed.booktitle`, in a copy of `agsm.bst`. I take it you've already applied some modifications, as referred to in the two earlier postings you've cross-referenced; let's assume the modified style file is called `agsm-mod.bst`. (Don't edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.) Now, proceed as follows:

- Open the file `agsm-mod.bst` in a text editor; the editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the function `format.in.ed.booktitle` (it should start around l. 393).
- In this function, locate the following two lines:

  ```
      { "{\em in} " booktitle quote * }
      { "{\em in} " format.editors.reverse * ", " * booktitle quote * }
  ```

  Delete the word `quote` in both lines. They should thus now read as follows:

  ```
      { "{\em in} " booktitle * }
      { "{\em in} " format.editors.reverse * ", " * booktitle * }
  ```
- Save the file `agsm-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution as well.
- Start using the new style file by providing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{agsm-mod}`. Be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Incidentally, because the `agsm` file is part of the `harvard` package, you should load the `har2nat` package instead of `natbib`. `har2nat` loads `natbib` *and* provides some additional macros that improve the interoperability of `agsm` with the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sss.bib}
@inproceedings{sss,
author = "G. Herman",
title = "Reconstruction of binary patterns from a few projections",
booktitle = "International Computing Symposium 1973",
publisher = "North-Holland Publ.\ Co.", 
address = "Amsterdam",
pages = "371-378",
year = "1973"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm-mod}

\begin{document}
\citep{sss}
\bibliography{sss}
\end{document}
```