# Remove quotation marks and maintain comma separator in natbib agsm

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm using `natbib` and the `agsm` harvard style for my bibliography. I would like to modify the style, such that the quotation marks for articles disappear.

I found an apparent solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47520/removing-the-quotations-marks-from-the-bibliography-using-harvard-style-agsm), which changes the agsm style file in line 698 from:

```
{ format.title quote "title" output.check }
```

to

```
{ format.title "title" output.check }
```

However I noticed that this way of removing quotations also results in a change of in-line citation lists.

So a former

```
Helgeson et al., 1981, Tanger and Helgeson, 1988
```

now becomes

```
Helgeson et al., 1981; Tanger and Helgeson, 1988
```

I'd like to keep the comma but have little clue where to start finding the reason for this. 
I hope somebody can help me!

Edit: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm-nq}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{Helgeson.1981,
    author = {Helgeson, H. C. and Kirkham, D. H. and Flowers, G. C.},
    year = {1981},
    title = {{Theoretical prediction of sth}},
    pages = {1249--1516},
    volume = {281},
    number = {10},
    journal = {{American Journal of Science}},
}
@article{Tanger.1988,
    author = {Tanger, J. C. and Helgeson, H. C.},
    year = {1988},
    title = {{Calculation of the thermodynamic stuff}},
    pages = {19--98},
    volume = {288},
    number = {1},
    journal = {{American Journal of Science}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
The revised HKF formalism \citep{Helgeson.1981,Tanger.1988} ...
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.