# Is there an easy way of removing quotation marks from bibliography when using agsm (harvard style)?

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I need help with the exact thing as been answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47526/181498! I do not understand the solution though. This is what I tried to do:

1. I found the `agsm.bst` file here: http://crpit.com/agsm.bst
2. I saved the text page in an ordinary text document and changed the line

   ```
   { format.title quote "title" output.check }
   ```

   as specified to

   ```
   { format.title "title" output.check }
   ```
3. I then saved the document as `agsm-nq.bst` in the same directory as the document that I'm currently working on and used `\bibliographystyle{agsm-nq}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`.

This did not work though. Is there not a simpler way of doing this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The the file from CTAN and not a third party: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/agsm.bst Other than that it sounds like the steps you went through were alright. There are a few caveats: Did you make absolutely sure that the new file is indeed called `agsm-nq.bst`? On Windows hidden file extensions may mean that the file is actually called `agsm-nq.bst.txt` or something to that effect. How exactly did things not work? Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX after the change to the document? Did you get any errors on the BibTeX run?

Comment: If you want to stick to `agsm`, then yes this is the easiest solution. You could try to find a similar style without quotation marks but there are many, many styles out there and depending on the desired output you may not find anything that fits.

Comment: Did you make sure that the line you edited as described in line item **2** above occurred in the `article` function? The reason I ask is that there's an identical-looking line in the `booklet` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I made sure that the change I made was under the article function but I noticed now that the file extension is not saved as .bst and I dont know how to make this happen. I tried googling for some conversion tool but there are none, it seems.

Comment: Using a more advanced text editor might help, for example Notepad++ in Windows (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Thank you! In the end the problem was that I did not save the file as .bst. Now it is working! Again, thanks everyone.

Comment: Now I feel like I want to change some more things with the agsm file. Hehe. For instance I want to have a punctuation after the the year "Gruber, S. (2017)." instead of a comma "Gruber, S. (2017)," and have the title in italics. Where can I change this? Dont know if this is supposed to be posted as a separate question on this forum or not.

Comment: @VictorGaleano it is best if you post a separate question about this. You can also read some manuals, for example http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf section 4.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As evil workaround you can set the category codes of the quotes to 9 (=ignore) just before the bibliographystyle. Note that this is evil and a workaround.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{test}.

\catcode`'=9
\catcode``=9
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Clever, but the evilness might have bad effects for many other things that could appear within a title, such as apostrophes, words themselves in quotes, etc.  So I think this should really not be recommended even as a workaround.

Comment: This looks simple enough but I get an error message when compiling the pdf:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\active
l.3 \catcode `"\active
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
)

Comment: @VictorGaleano are you sure you copied it correctly, including the backtick characters? Anyway, as Alan Munn commented, this is not really a solution, it is just a small demonstration of the `\catcode` command. As a real solution you should implement the `format.title` approach from the linked question.

Comment: Yeah, I think I copied it correctly. Anyhow, I got it working with the format.title approach. :) Thanks!